# NODEJS - Call function between worker_threads and parent (or vice versa)

Tags: node.js, postmessage, node-worker-threads

- Nodejs supports communication between worker and parent using the postMessage method, however it only supports one-way communication.
- If you want two-way communication by calling a worker function from the parent and waiting to receive the worker's response (or vice versa), you can use the worker-messenger library on npmjs.
  [https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-messenger](https://stackoverflow.com)

- very easy to use it, such as:

```
result = await messenger.callParent('testParentFunc', 'args', timeout)
result = await messenger.callWorker('testFunction', 'args', timeout)
```

It works by postingMessage and waiting for the response.
Hope it is useful to you.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question and thus doesn't fit what you can/should post as a question on stackoverflow.